# Babel plugin (babel-plugin-module-alias) with React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs

I am wanting to use [babel-plugin-module-alias](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-alias) for transforming module paths from `../../../../components/foo` into `app/components/foo` in my React Native project.

I have attempted to modify the babel config in two places independently, neither works.

One, at the root of my project next to the `index.ios.js`:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["babel-plugin-module-alias", [
      { "src": "./app", "expose": "app" }
    ]]
  ]
}
```

And two, at `/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/.babelrc`:

```
{
  "retainLines": true,
  "compact": true,
  "comments": false,
  "plugins": [
    ["babel-plugin-module-alias", [
      { "src": "./app", "expose": "app" }
    ]],
    "syntax-async-functions",
    "syntax-class-properties",
    "syntax-trailing-function-commas",
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-es2015-arrow-functions",
    "transform-es2015-block-scoping",
    "transform-es2015-classes",
    "transform-es2015-computed-properties",
    "transform-es2015-constants",
    "transform-es2015-destructuring",
    ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs", {"strict": false, "allowTopLevelThis": true}],
    "transform-es2015-parameters",
    "transform-es2015-shorthand-properties",
    "transform-es2015-spread",
    "transform-es2015-template-literals",
    "transform-flow-strip-types",
    "transform-object-assign",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-react-display-name",
    "transform-react-jsx",
    "transform-regenerator",
    "transform-es2015-for-of"
  ],
  "sourceMaps": false
}
```

It doesn't throw any errors, simply trying to require a module as such `import MyComponent from 'app/components/MyComponent';` yields the error:

`Unable to resolve module app/components/MyComponent from .... Invalid directory /Users/node_modules/app/components/MyComponent`.

I have tried nuking every cache I'm aware of:

```
watchman watch-del-all
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*
./node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh start --resetCache
```

Any further ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After upgrading npm/node/react-native/react to its latest:

```
react-native: ^0.29.0
react: 15.2.1
npm: 3.10.3
node: 6.3.0
```

Then:

```
watchman watch-del-all
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

This issue went away.

You can check more about this issue here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968 and https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-alias/issues/29

Comment: A better github issue for context is actually https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-alias/issues/29.  This issue was confirmed fixed as of RN 0.24